# How deep should posts be set for an 8 foot privacy fence?

Tags: wood, fence

I am planning to build an 8 foot fence and will use galvanized post due to high moisture in the area. Looking for some advice regarding the depth of the post. These are 10 foot post so I was planning to place them 2- 2 1/2 feet deep and secure with up to 100 pounds of concrete mix. The post will be 6 feet apart and I will use 2x4x12 stringers. Due to the lumber shortage I will have to use 1x6x8 PT pine pickets instead of cypress. There is 125 feet to build. Any ideas on the depth to place the posts? Thanks

Comment: Or [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/137885/what-is-a-reasonable-depth-and-diameter-for-postholes-dug-in-clay-soil-to-suppor)? Or [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/140477/manufacturer-pairs-6-ft-tall-vinyl-fence-with-8-ft-posts-should-i-find-9-ft-po)? Or [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72911/how-deep-in-ground-should-i-install-4x4-pt-fence-posts)?

Comment: Rule of thumb: at least a third of the length out of the ground should be in the ground. Sometimes closer to half...

Comment: It depends where you live. The west coast areas close to the coast have to be 2x as deep

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I'll dig a 30 inch deep by 10 inch diameter hole. Fence is in middle alabama so no freeze issues.  Not much wind except during the hurricanes and tornadoes, but not much to do about that. Project starts next week..i hope. Thanks.